# How to convert Java foreach loop in a Scala equivalent?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I'm trying to convert below Java code to Scala:

```
Map<String, List<String>> allEntriesMap = getEntries();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> allEntriesMapEntry : allEntriesMap
        .entrySet()) {
}
```

Here is the current Scala version of above Java code:

```
var allEntriesMap : Map[String, List[String]] = getEntries();
for (allEntriesMap.entrySet[String, List[String]] allEntriesMapEntry :
        allEntriesMap.entrySet()) {
}
```

I'm receiving this error for line

```
for (allEntriesMap.entrySet[String, List[String]] allEntriesMapEntry :
```

> illegal start of simple pattern

How can above code be finished so that it performs same Java functionality but written in Scala?

Comment: Please, read some tutorials before proceeding. Copy/pasting code from java to scala is the worst way to learn.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you use incorrect syntax. This

```
for (allEntriesMap.entrySet[String, List[String]] allEntriesMapEntry : allEntriesMap.entrySet()) {

    }
```

Should be written as:

```
for (entry: Map.Entry[String, List[String]] <- allEntriesMap.entrySet()) {

}
```

or simply

```
for (entry <- allEntriesMap.entrySet) {

}
```

Moreover, if you're using java collections type you have to import `scala.collections.JavaConversions._` into scope (that will implicitly convert java collections into scala ones, so you may use all set of operations on them).

Comment: Better use `JavaConverters` and `asScala` to have better control over conversions.

Comment: I think the main thing that at least was on my side was "import scala.collection.JavaConversions._"

Answer (score 1):

This is a syntax error, because the `for` loop uses different syntax in Scala than it does in Java. (It doesn't use the colon for anything -- it uses the left-pointing arrow instead.)

Your code should look like the following:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

for ((key, value) <- getEntries()) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply some function for every element of the map by using foreach(), map() etc. functions. So you will deal with tuple in Scala as with Map.Entry object in Java.

E.g. you can use following code to flush all values in your map.

```
var allEntriesMap : Map[String, List[String]] = getEntries()

allEntriesMap.foreach((arg: (String, List[String])) => {arg._2 = List.empty[String]})
```